# Eliminate render-blocking resources critical JS/CSS inline and deferring all non-critical JS/styles

Tags: html, jquery, scripting, render-blocking

Resources are blocking the first paint of your page. Consider delivering critical JS/CSS inline and deferring all non-critical JS/styles.

I have to do find the blocking JS CDN and Download and link file and improve some CSS also but I do not understand Exactly Solution ,Anyone can help me